# What is a correct way to pass an event as parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, I don't know if I stated the question correcly. I will try to explain my situation below.
I have a method:

```
public void FocusTargetZoom(Transform target, 
                            float focusTime, 
                            float zoomFactorPercentage, 
                            OnStopFocusing onStopFocusing = null, 
                            bool lockMovement = true)
{
    if (lockMovement)
    {
        Character.Instance.LockMovement();
    }
    if(onStopFocusing != null)
    {
        //StopFocusing = onStopFocusing;
    }
    zoomFactor = initFOV * zoomFactorPercentage / 100f;

    FocusOnTarget(target, focusTime);
}
```

where `OnStopFocusing` is my delegate void. This `FocusTargetZoom` method will be called from any other object, for example an object, who has `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` events. Now, what I am trying to do is *pass the OnTriggerExit event* to the `FocusTargetZoom` method, so anytime my `OnTriggerExit` method will be called, it would stop zooming. Basically, the plan is:

1. Call `FocusTargetZoom` method from **Caller**;
2. Wait till **Caller** do something and trigger passed event to the method;
3. Stop zooming.

Yet I'm not sure if this is the right approach for this kind of problem. If you have some insights, please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `event` is something that happens and **triggers** something else, that **listens** to it. So an `event` has a *Listener* and not a *Caller*.

You're using an `Action` here (a void delegate is basically an Action), and not an `event`.

To achieve your desired result you want a **check** to see if your target is still valid, so you need a `delegate` that returns something (such as a `Func<bool>`).

This `Func<bool>`, needs to returns false when we have the `OnTriggerExit`.
Also, you need to pass this `Func<bool>` to the method who is doing the focusing (`FocusOnTarget` in your case).

```
    public void FocusTargetZoom(Transform target, float focusTime, float zoomFactorPercentage, Func<bool> whenToStopFunc, bool lockMovement = true)
    {
        if (lockMovement)
        {
            Character.Instance.LockMovement();
        }

        StopFocusing = whenToStopFunc;

        zoomFactor = initFOV * zoomFactorPercentage / 100f;

        FocusOnTarget(target, focusTime, whenToStopFunc);
    }


private void FocusOnTarget(Transform target, float focusTime, Func<bool> whenToStopFunc)
{
       while(notYetFocused)
       {
           if(whenToStopFunc != null && !whenToStopFunc())
           { KeepFocusing(); }
       }
}
```

And the caller MonoBehaviour requires to be like this:

```
public void Caller : MonoBehaviour
{
     bool isSelected = false;

     void IsThisSelected() => isSelected;

     private CallTheFocus() => _focusClass.FocusTargetZoom(transform, 1f, 1f, IsThisSelected);

     private void OnTriggerEnter() => isSelected = true;
     private void OnTriggerExit() => isSelected = false;

}
```